# How do I refer to the module scope from within an ES 6 module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In a browser based environment, how would I refer to a variable inside module-level scope if it had the same name as a function parameter within the module?

For e.g. if I had the following:

**Module Foo**

```
let thisFoo = undefined;

export function do(foo) {
  thisFoo = foo;
}
```

I could assign the value of the function parameter `foo` to the module-scoped variable `thisFoo` because they are named differently.

But what if I had named the module level variable also by the same name as the function parameter, how would I refer to the module level variable?

**Module Foo**

```
let foo = undefined;

export function do(foo) {

  // I'd like to refer to the module level variable foo
  // for the LHS, and assign to it the function level
  // variable foo

  // ???
  // obviously, doesn't make any sense
  foo = foo;

  // this would still refer to the window object, right?
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's no different from when you want to access an outer variable with the same name as an inner variable, in any environment - only real solution is to use different variable names.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to refer to the module scope explicitly from within a function or block inside the module?

Comment: You can't. `let` does not bind names to `window` (thankfully). Plus, you're in a module. Just name them differently

Comment: @Li357 Of course, `let` doesn't bind names to the `window` object, and hence the question. Is there a way to refer to the module-scope?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 No AFAIK. It doesn't make sense though even if you could. Why not just name differently? JavaScript has no map of bound names in the current module (or module-scope as you call it).

Comment: Thanks. No, you're right. It doesn't make sense. There isn't a way to even explicitly address *any* block-scope, so why should modules be any special. I was simply thinking if there was. Thanks for the confirmation.